# $V = R^{2}$, and $S$ consists of all vectors $(x, y)$ satisfying $x^{2} - y^{2} = 0$ ...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V = R^{2}$, and $S$ consists of all vectors $(x, y)$ satisfying $x^{2} - y^{2} = 0$

Express $S$ in set notation and determine  whether it's a subspace of the given vector space $V$.

-I have done several problems similar to this, all involving sets of numbers not an actual equation, I am not sure at all how to approach this. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are $x^2$ and $y^2$ in $\mathbf R^{\color{red}{n}}$?

Comment: my mistake i meant to write $V = R^{2}$,

Comment: @Bye_World -- Actually it is closed under scalar multiplication.